# How to fix Fragment showing in AndroidStudio activity but not in emulator/device

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Before making this activity I had another activity where I used fragments and navigation component just fine but that activity had an empty layout which only contained <fragment, this one is more complex and it has a navigation view coming from the left (which I have closed in following picture) and also a custom "toolbar" (it's a RelativeLayout functioning as a toolbar but isn't of the Toolbar class, it shouldn't matter in this issue).

So in this activity when I use the <fragment, the fragment does show in AndroidStudio preview but not in the activity, here is a demonstration:
[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I think the issue is caused by the specific fragment cause if I put any other fragment in the activity layout the fragment does appear. This fragment is special because about half of it is out of bounds of the phone due to an animation, but that still doesn't explain why it shows correctly in AndroidStudio. Here is the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainmenu_circle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
        />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rotatingView"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:rotation="45"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="115dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="20"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="30"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="115dp"
            android:rotation="135"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="40"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="50"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
            android:rotation="225"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="60"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="70"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="115dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:rotation="315"
            android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle_button"
            android:text="80"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: Problematic fragment]